# Prove that any prime of the form $2^{k} + 1$ is a Fermat prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

That is, prove that for any prime of the form $2^{k} + 1$, the only prime divisor of $k$ is $2$.

Say $k = ab$ where $a$ is even, $b$ is odd. We can show that this leads to a contradiction unless $b$ = 1, since if $b$ doesn't equal 1, then $2^{a} + 1$ will divide $2^{k} + 1$, contradicting the fact that $2^{k} + 1$ is prime.

We know by this argument that we can't take, say, $k$ = 10, because then we can take $a = 2$ and $b = 5$, which, by the previous argument, will contradict the fact that $2^{k} + 1$ is prime. But I'm not sure how to express this point correctly to finish off the proof.

Comment: What do you think is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $p$ (not $2$) divides $k$, for some prime $p$. Then we know $p$ must divide one of $a$ or $b$. But $b$ is 1, so it must divide $a$. But $a$ is even, so $p$ must be even. Hence $p$ must be 2.